# past tense and/or conditional

Tags: word-usage

e.g.
I didn't get to where I am now unless ...
or
I wouldn't have got where I am now ...
Are these both correct?
The first sentence I found in a EFL series New English File.
I have never heard this used in HampshireUK nor have I ever used it myself.

Comment: What page was that, from which level book?

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't put the full sentences for both? Unless you edit your question to include them, your question might be closed as "off-topic".

Comment: Are you sure that isn't *I didn't get to where I am now by ...*

Comment: The second one starts off correct...can't say more though because the rest of the sentence is missing.

Comment: This just sounds like a misquotation of CJ from "The Fall And Rise Of Reginald Perrin".

Answer (score 0):

The second of the two choices (i.e., "I wouldn't have gotten where I am now") is correct. The "unless" is a marker of the conditional mood because it signifies that the facts of your sentence wouldn't have been true unless the condition following "unless" had been met (i.e., the fact of "getting where you are now" hinges on the condition).